# App.js module not found; Can't resolve, Failed to compile

Tags: javascript, compiler-errors

I am new to javaScript and am having an interesting problem. Here is some context; I am running windows 10, node v15, I have downloaded expo and am using visual studio. The command I am using to run my code is npm start.

The problem happens when I add the code to line 4 of app.js. I am trying to import a file that is simply just a button. The code compiles and loads fine until I add line 4.

The error I get looks like this;

"C:/Windows/System32/pleasework/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'C:WindowsSystem32pleasework"

Thank you for any insight at all!

App.js CODE

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import buttonWelcome from 'C:\Windows\System32\pleasework\node_modules\sweet.js';

export default class App extends Component() {
  render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Welcome</Text>
      <buttonWelcome text='Login' color='red' />
    </View>
  );
}
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 32,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
});
```

button CODE, name of file is sweet.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const buttonWelcome = props => {
    const content = (
        <View style={[style.button, {backgroundColor: props.color}]}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{props.text}</Text>
        </View>
    )
    return <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onPress}>{content}</TouchableOpacity>
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    button: {
        padding: 16,
        width: 200,
        borderRadius: 24,
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    text: {
        color: 'white',
        fontSize: 20
    }
})

export default buttonWelcome;
```

Comment: That library should already exist in your `node_modules` folder at the root of your project, so you should only have to reference the folder name for that library/dependency you're trying to use. If it's NOT in your `node_modules` (you never installed it local to your project) you need to install it as a local dependency using: `npm install dependency_name`

Comment: Just to be clear, do I want my sweet.js file in my node_modules folder? Or just in my project folder itself? I have fixed my import statement as u can see in the comments below but I am still receiving the same error unfortunately.

Comment: There's a `package.json` file at the root of your project. That file shows you any specific dependencies (libraries) you have added to your project (one of them should already be react along with whatever version you're using). Find the actual library for sweet.js in the npm registry (https://www.npmjs.com/) and add it to your project. It will show you the exact way to download your specific library, which looks like this: `npm i library_name`. This ensures the package is downloaded locally to your `node_modules` folder, then you just reference the `node_modules` library/folder name on import.

Comment: You may want to spend a little time researching how node projects work and how the `package.json` manages your project dependencies. Learn how to install new libraries/dependencies via npm through the command line. Learn the difference between normal dependencies and developer dependencies. It's super important to understand how dependencies work if you're going to be building a React app or be working with node projects, going forward.

Comment: OKay noted, I will do that. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

try a relative url with forward slashes:

```
import buttonWelcome from '../sweet.js';
```

btw you should never put source files in node_modules - that's only for node_modules code..

Comment: okay noted... I tried that import statement and still got the same error unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

The import statement is wrong.
It should be

```
import buttonWelcome from './sweet.js';
```

As you can see it is using linux style file path which is important. This will work on both linux and windows.

Comment: Okay, I have tried both './sweet.js' and '../sweet.js'. I am still getting the same error. Could it be something within my actual file directory? I have confirmed sweet.js is in the project folder along with app.js

Comment: Wait now I get "Reference error: Component not defined
 
It is pointing to line 6 in app.js
> 6 | export default class App extends Component() {

Comment: You need `import React, { Component } from 'react'`. Look More info: https://reactnative.dev/docs/tutorial

Comment: Now I am getting " TypeError: Cannot set property 'props' of undefined" and it is pointing to a line in /node_modules/react/cjs/react.developoment.js:428

Comment: @guts716 can you please provide details about your project structure and full js file code where the error is occurring. This way we can provide exact solution.